# MailChimp API v3.0 - Can't update Tag of existing member

Tags: api, curl, tags, mailchimp

I'm having some problems trying to add/update the tags from an existing user.

When I update an existing member informations, it does not update the Tag (using method "PATCH"). It updates all fields, but not the Tag. It does create the tag when i create a new member in the list (using method "POST").

The code that I'm using is:

```
function add_suscriber($data)
    {
    //Data Format:
        //$data = array(
            //'apikey'        => $api_key,
            //'listid'        => $list_id,
            //'email_address' => $email,
            //'status'     => $suscripcion,
            //'tags'  => array($tags),
            //'merge_fields'  => array(
            //    'FNAME' => $nombre,       //nombre
            //    'LNAME' => $apellido,     //apellido
            //    'PAIS'  => $pais          //pais de residencia
            //    )
            //);
    $API_URL =   'https://' . substr($data['apikey'],strpos($data['apikey'],'-') + 1 ) . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $data['listid'] . '/members/' . md5(strtolower($data['email_address']));

    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode( 'user:'.$data['apikey'] )));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data) ); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);  
    curl_close($ch);

    $response = json_decode($result);                
    }
```

With this, when it is a new user I have no problem; but if the user already exists (in any audience) everything is updated but not the tag.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar issue and this worked.

Here is what I did:

1. Get the subscriber hash of the existing member using

$subscriberHash =  $MailChimp->subscriberHash($contactEmail);

2. Call the tag update API

   ```
        $tagsSelected = ['ASH Tag 33','ASH Tag2 665'];
        foreach ($tagsSelected as $key=>$tag)
        {

            $tagArr['name']     = $tag;
            $tagArr['status']   = 'active'; //Put status = "active" for adding "inactive" for removing.

            $tagNameArrFnl[]    = $tagArr;
        }
        $parameters['tags'] = $tagNameArrFnl;


        $addTags  = $MailChimp->post('/lists/'.$listId.'/members/'.$subscriberHash .'/tags',$parameters);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update the tags for a user via a patch.  It only works as describes in the documentation when you are adding a new subscriber.

I talked to Mailchimp and suggested they at least make that clearer in the documentation.

My workaround is to use
/lists/{list_id}/segments/{segment_id}/members